How to integrate pallet-asset?
I want to integrate pallet-asset into the substrate-node-template.
What all other pallets need to integrate with pallet-asset to get assets functionalities?
Thanks

I assume you have already set up the basic runtime.
It could work independently.
Refer to the official template node. It shows that pallet-asset doesn't depend on any other special pallets.
https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/a9aeabe923dae63ab76ab290951cb9183c51f59c/substrate/bin/node/runtime/src/lib.rs#L1646-L1667
It depends on the pallet-balances, but I believe it's included in the basic runtime. Typically, every chain incorporates the pallet-balances. The same reason for the frame-system. :)
https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/a9aeabe923dae63ab76ab290951cb9183c51f59c/substrate/bin/node/runtime/src/lib.rs#L1651
